# Take input from keyboard and edit existing text file

Tags: c++

I have been having problems with my code and now I am lost.
I need the user to use the console to read from the text file and update it with new records.
For example I am doing a football type project. I have 9 players in a football team and I want to be able to add new players from the console, so when added it will start from the last entry in the file and add a new one so there would be 10 total players if a new player is added.

```
void addFootballPlayer(Football footballPlayer[], int *f); {
        string forename, surname;
    int defence, strike, midfield;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("FootballTeam.txt");

    cout << "Enter first name ";
    cin >> forename;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter surname ";
    cin >> surname;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter strike power  ";
    cin >> strike;
    cout << "Enter defence power  ";
    cin >> defence;
    cout << "Enter midfield power  ";
    cin >> midfield;
```

Comment: so what's the problem? complete the code.

Comment: So can you explain which part you are struggling with?

Comment: I'm not to sure how to write to the file, I can read the file just not sure how to write to it. I have researched a lot and went through some YouTube videos but they don't seem to be what I need. Thanks

Comment: Checkout: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write to your file using the file stream you have defined once you have taken your inputs and you can do that using `fout` as follows. Additionally, there are different modes in which you could open a file for writing to it, which you can go through [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/).

```
    fout.open("FootballTeam.txt");

    cout << "Enter first name ";
    cin >> forename;
    fout << forename << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter surname ";
    cin >> surname;
    fout << surname << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter strike power  ";
    cin >> strike;
    fout << strike << " ";
    cout << "Enter defence power  ";
    cin >> defence;
    fout << defence << " ";
    cout << "Enter midfield power  ";
    cin >> midfield;
    fout << midfield << "\n";
```

Open and take a look at `FootballTeam.txt` to find what the above snippet does.

Hope that helps.